# Clickhouse SQL: IN operator fails on the empty parenthesized list of expressions

Tags: sql, clickhouse, sql-in

Using ClickHouse, my query is failing if I pass into the query an empty set to `IN` clause.

This works:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE '2' IN ('2','3');
```

This fails:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE '2' IN ();
```

Error:

```
Expected one of: token, DoubleColon, non-empty parenthesized list of expressions. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 22.3.7.28 (official build))
```

Apparently some flavours of SQL allow to not fail syntactically because of using an empty set inside an `IN` clause, treating the result of the condition as a `false`.
In [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) I tested this and both work from a syntactical point of view.

**EDIT**: Only SQLite, not SQL. SQL spec [explicitly does not allow](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-1999-grammar.html#_8_4_in_predicate) an empty `IN ()`.

Is it there a setting in Clickhouse to go either way, is it possible for ClickHouse to not fail on this query?
I haven't found such setting [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#join_use_nulls).

Comment: you need to add somtion like '', that's the rule

Comment: That would be a set with an element being an empty string. I would like an empty set.

Comment: *Apparently some flavours of SQL allow to not fail syntactically because of using an empty set inside an IN clause* only SQLite allows it and the link you tried your code runs on SQLite.

Comment: You're right there. I can see here that the SQL spec explictly does not allow it: https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-1999-grammar.html#_8_4_in_predicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [arrayExists](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#arrayexistsfunc-arr1-) instead:

```sql
SELECT 1
WHERE arrayExists(x -> x == '2', cast([/* list of checked strings */], 'Array(String)'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I accept it as it gives a proper workaround solution to the original problem.
If it is of use to anyone, using an actual table field, then it should be `SELECT ... WHERE arrayExists(x -> x == field, cast([/* list of checked strings */], 'Array(String)'))`.